# How do I get countUp Javascript package working?

Tags: javascript, package

I'm trying to implement the countUp Javascript package and I'm getting an error: [CountUp] target is null or undefined. The gitHub repository for the countUp Javascript package is https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js. My question, for individuals who have experience with this package, is how can I fix my code to avoid this error? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<title>Count Up Test</title>
<head>
<script src="countUp.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id="tester">100</h1>

<script>

var options = {
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ',',
    decimal: '.',
};

tester1 = document.getElementById('tester').innerHTML;
console.log(tester1);

var test1 = new CountUp('tester1', 100, 1500, 0, 2.5, options);
if (!test1.error) {
    test1.start();
} else {
    console.error(test1.error);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding in an eventListener for the DOM, I've tried using window.onload, and the console.log(tester1) shows 100

Comment: Not sure why this question was down voted. It would be helpful if the person who down voted this to provide some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `tester1` to `tester` in the below line....

```
var test1 = new CountUp('tester', 100, 1500, 0, 2.5, options);
```

Assuming you have an html element like this...

```
<h1 id="tester">100</h1>
```

**Notice that the id of the html element matches the string passed to CountUp ("tester")**

The first parameter to the constructor of `CountUp` is a string representing the `id` attribute of the html element you want to use. Basically, `CountUp` will call `getElementById` itself and look up your DOM node for you.